# $X$ given $\Theta$ is $\operatorname{Poisson}(\Theta)$, $\Theta$ is distributed as $\operatorname{Gamma}(a,b)$. What are the Mean and Variance of $X$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expectation, poisson-distribution

This is what I have so far:

Joint Distribution (product of pmf of $X$ and pdf of $\Theta$)  $$f(x,\theta)=\frac{\theta ^xe^{-\theta}}{x!}\frac{b^a}{\Gamma (a)}\theta ^{a-1}e^{-b\theta}$$ and with a little algebra we can get $$f(x,\theta)=\frac{1}{x!}\frac{b^a}{(b+1)^{x+a}}\frac{\Gamma (x+a)}{\Gamma (a)}\cdot\frac{(b+1)^{x+a}}{\Gamma (x+a)} \theta ^{(x+a)-1}e^{-(b+1)\theta}$$ for easy derivation of the pdf of $X$: $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x!}\frac{b^a}{(b+1)^{x+a}}\frac{\Gamma (x+a)}{\Gamma (a)}\int_0^\infty\frac{(b+1)^{x+a}}{\Gamma (x+a)} \theta ^{(x+a)-1}e^{-(b+1)\theta}d\theta$$ leaving us with$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x!}\frac{b^a}{(b+1)^{x+a}}\frac{\Gamma (x+a)}{\Gamma (a)}$$
Which looks kind of similar to some kind of beta distribution?
What kind of distribution can this be identified as?
If it's not a standard distribution, how can I calculate the raw moments?
Is integration or summation appropriate (Changing $x!$ to $\Gamma (x+1)$)?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: It should be clear that this is not a bounded distribution since the Poisson distribution is not bounded.

Comment: If you solely want to calculate the mean and variance of $X$, you can just apply the law of total expectation and variance respectively, without calculating the marginal distribution of $X$.

Comment: I've answered essentially this same question here before. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Where you have $a^b,$ did you intend $b^a$? $\qquad$

Comment: And for the name of the distribution, I can only find Poisson-Gamma (mixture) distribution.

Comment: ah, yes I did mean $b^a$. I will edit. Thank you.

@BGM thank you, I will look into the Law of Total Expectation.

Comment: It's a negative binomial distribution -- the kind supported on the set $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\},$ not the kind called the "Pascal distribution". $\qquad$

Comment: Wow, if you change the gamma functions to their factorial equivalents and a little algebra, you end up with $${x+a-1 \choose x} \left(1-\frac{1}{b+1}\right)^a \left(\frac{1}{b+1}\right)^x$$ which is negative binomial! Amazing, thank you @MichaelHardy

Comment: @MichaelHardy, could you please briefly explain what you mean by your comment: 'It should be clear that this is not a bounded distribution since the Poisson distribution is not bounded.'?

Comment: @bandwagoner : Suppose, for example, that $\Theta=3.$ Then no matter how big a number $c$ is, you have $\Pr(X>c) > 0.$ So the distribution of $X$ has no upper bound. And the same is true if $\Theta$ is any other number. In fact $\Pr(X> c) = \operatorname{E}(\Pr( X>c \mid \Theta)) >0.$ So the distribution of $X$ has no upper bound. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ f(x,\theta) \,d\theta = \frac{\theta^x e^{-\theta}}{x!} \cdot \frac 1 {\Gamma(a)} (b\theta)^{a-1} e^{-b\theta} (b\,d\theta) $$

$$
\operatorname{E}(X) = \operatorname{E}(\operatorname{E}(X\mid \Theta)) = \operatorname{E}(\Theta) = \frac a b.
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(X) & = \operatorname{E}(\operatorname{var}(X\mid\Theta)) + \operatorname{var}(\operatorname{E}(X\mid\Theta)) \\[10pt]
& = \operatorname{E}(\Theta) + \operatorname{var}(\Theta).
\end{align}

The actual *distribution* of $X$ given $\Theta$ is a negative binomial distribution, but I can't find the various occasions when I've posted about that. I think one of them may have been about three months ago.

Comment: +1. To summarize this up, the full distribution is **not** needed to compute the expectation and the variance.

Comment: This is a much simpler way of approaching the question asked. I did not think to use these expectation laws. Thanks.